# Can't find mosConfig_absolute_path in configuration.php

Tags: content-management-system, joomla, website-hosting

I am trying to move my Joomla1 website from localhost to my bluehost.com domain. For testing I have created a subdirectory on my domain for testing and moved all my Joomla! files to this. I have created this subdirectory under the public_html folder.

I am using different menus on the front page (custom page) and remaining pages. My problem is that the menu items on the front page are looking for pages in a subdirectory named **joomla** instead of looking for pages in my subdirectory (**testing**)

Based on suggestions from some websites I thought changing **mosConfig_absolute_path** will help but my configuration.php file in the **testing** subdirectory doesn't have a property called mosConfig_absolute_path. I do not face this problem on any of the menu items on the other pages.

Can someone please help me with this problem and how I should overcome it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable you're talking about is `$mosConfig_absolute_path` rather than `$msConfig_absolute_path`. You will also need to reset `$mosConfig_live_site`.

Also, migrating to Joomla! 1.5 would avoid this issue entirely; it automatically detects your base path and URL.

Comment: Thanks. I came to know it was mosConfig later, but I dont see that either. And the base path is not getting recognized. If you see the question, the menu links on the first page do not go to the right place.

Comment: Have you tried adding $mosConfig_live_site to configuration.php? Are there any $mosConfig variables in this file at all?